# Eliminate one argument from kwargs. Is that possible?

Tags: python, keras

I am working with built-in functions in Keras to create XCeption ensembles. In my ensemble, each Xception net will have a different weights initialization approaches considered. The initialization techniques are the following:

```
switcher = {
            0: Orthogonal(gain=1.0, seed=None),
            1: lecun_uniform(seed=None),
            2: VarianceScaling(scale=1.0, mode='fan_in', distribution='normal', seed=None),
            3: RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None),
            4: RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05, seed=None),
            5: TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None),
            6: glorot_normal(seed=None),
            7: glorot_uniform(seed=None),
            8: he_normal(seed=None),
            9: he_uniform(seed=None) 
        }
```

Ok, so, for each of the several CNNs in my ensemble, I instantiate the Xception net like the following.

```
base_model=xception.Xception(include_top=False, weights=None, kernelinitializer=xception_ensemble.switcher.get(init_var))
```

To include kernelinitializer argument in order to initialize the Xception weights, I had to make several modifications in my 
python3.6/site-packages/keras_applications/xception.py file.

The first modification was including the variable kernelinitializer in the constructor of the CNN, as the following:

```
def Xception(include_top=True,
             weights='imagenet',
             input_tensor=None,
             input_shape=None,
             pooling=None,
             classes=1000, kernel_initializer="he_normal", **kwargs):
```

I put "he_normal" just because it must have a default value if not informed.

Then, the next step was adding the kernel_initializer value to initialize any convolutional layer of the Xception CNN. For example:

```
residual = layers.Conv2D(256, (1, 1), strides=(2, 2),
                             padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)(x)
```

However there is one problem here. The code does the following thing

```
backend, layers, models, keras_utils = get_submodules_from_kwargs(kwargs)
```

So, this function considers as input all arguments (including my alien one) to build submodules of the CNN. However, my argument is (obviously) not recognized by the function. So, the following error happens:

> File
>   "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_applications/**init**.py",
>   line 20, in get_submodules_from_kwargs
>       raise TypeError('Invalid keyword argument: %s', key) TypeError: ('Invalid keyword argument: %s', 'kernelinitializer')

Is there a way to eliminate my kernelinitializer variable from these kwards? is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension to get a copy of your kwargs without a specific item:

```
{key: value for key, value in kwargs.items() if key != 'kernelinitializer'}
```

Comment: Is this a new variable that I can send to another function? thanks for your answer

Comment: @mad yes it is.